# Using fnmatch for this particular pattern

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that looks into specific directory and finds matches for a specific file format.

The function format would be as follows:

```
def file_pattern_match(self, fundCodes, startDate, endDate):

    # set a file pattern
    file_pattern = 'unmapped_{fund}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(fund=somethinghere, start=startDate, end=endDate) 

    # look in the unmappeddir and see if there's a file with that name

    # if the there is load the positions
    pass
```

Here's where i'm getting a little confused. `fundCodes` will be an array of fundCodes. So this function will have to search through the files in a directory and see if there's a match.

calling it:

`file_pattern_match(['FUND1', 'FUND2', 'FUND3'], '20180203', '20180204')`

should find a file like this:

`unmapped_FUND1_20180203_20180204.csv`

I was thinking of using regex but i'm not sure how that would work with an array of strings.

Comment: Either check the files once for each pattern, or check the patterns once for each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your functions needs to return a DataFrame of the data and that only one code matches the file your function would look like

```
import pandas as pd    
import os

def file_pattern_match(self, fundCodes, startDate, endDate):
    # Get a list of the files
    files = os.listdir(unmappeddir)
    # loop through the codes and chack if they are in the files
    for check_fund in fundCodes:
        # set a file pattern
        file_pattern = 'unmapped_{fund}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(fund=check_fund, 
            start=startDate, end=endDate) 

        # look in the unmappeddir and see if there's a file with that name
        if file_pattern in files:
            return pd.read_csv(file_pattern)
```

Comment: Ahhh yes, I could grab a list of all the files and see if there's a match for it. How would I pass in the `fund` variable in the `file_pattern` though? Would that be a nested loop since `fundCodes` is a list itself?

Comment: sorry forgot to add this part, am updating my answer

Comment: Oh woops, yeah that makes total sense now. Thank you!